# Are bootnodes central nodes?

Tags: ethereum

I'm attempting to create a private PoA ethereum network and I've been using morden, ropsten and rinkeby for a while. I didn't realize before that network nodes discovery is made by a connection to some bootnodes. Are these nodes central? And thus, isn't it a big decentralization lack?

I mean, if bootnodes are only few and are set at the beginning of a network creation, we can imagine that those nodes are fraudulent (in the sense of pointing to fraudulent BC nodes). No?

Thank's in advance for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the bootnodes are central, and for the main and test networks are hardcoded in [bootnodes.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/params/bootnodes.go).

The "enode://" protocol includes the public key as well as the IP address for these nodes, so you're still effectively trusting the Ethereum Foundation, but it should be secure. From there additional peers will be shared with your node.

Some more details on how connectivity works can be found on the wiki [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network).

Comment: Really !!! So as i said, it's a huge decentralization lack, no? no way to do without bootnodes? (or at least without central bootnodes) something like giving the possibility to peers to create their own bootnodes? so that we get closer to BC decentralisation paradigm

Comment: As currently implemented there is a need for the bootnodes to seed the initial peer network. That said, if you want to run your own private network you can specify your own trusted bootnodes, so you're ultimately in control of your network. Distributed Hash Tables is a good starting point for further reading on the topic of decentralization in peer to peer networks.